# Assigning same image to all associated products of configurable product Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2.2

I have written a script in Magento 2 to create configurable and simple (associated) products pragmatically. While running the script i found that Magento is creating the copy of same image file for each product. Whereas i think we can assign the same image for all its associated products of 1 type.

For Ex: We have 10 simple products for color Black of different size. In this case all the product with individual size will have same product image but actually Magento will create 10 copy of same image and assign with each product.

```
$this->productFactory->addImageToMediaGallery($image, $mediaAttribute, false, false);
```

Is there as way we can assign the same products images to all associated products without creating the new copy for each product ?